# Адаптация Entry к размеру окна Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, width

Похожий на мой вопрос уже был задан на StackOverflow, но все же не такой.
Мне нужно поместить Entry в окно так, чтобы он бесконечно растягивался при изменении размера окна.
Для этого я поместил Entry в Frame со свойством `expand=True` таким образом:

```
window = Tk()
#...
Textframe = Frame(window)
Textframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
Textedit = Entry(Textframe)  
Textedit.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, expand=True)

window.mainloop()
```

И тут Entry адаптируется только по вертикали, а не по обеим направлениям.
Возможно я не знаю некоторых аргументов frame или самого Entry, но догадался только до этого.
Помогите мне разобраться как сделать чтобы ширина Entry была всегда по окну.

P.S: Разобрался, глупо получается как то. `side=LEFT` просто не нужен, а вместо значения Y у `fill=Y` должно быть BOTH, про что я забыл.

Comment: Если разобрались, добавьте решение ответом или удалите вопрос.

Comment: Кажется добавил

Comment: Не добавили. Вопрос в данный момент без ответа. Ответ нужно добавить в поле "Ваш ответ" ниже.

Answer (score 0):

side=LEFT не нужен, а вместо значения Y у fill=Y должно быть BOTH.